# unable to convert mp3 files to text format only support .wav files in java

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I have created an application but it is only support .wav files to convert audio to text. It is not showing any answers when giving .mp3 files .. I am using sphinx for to convert audio files to text. My question is that why it is not converting to text from .MP3?

Comment: You have more chance of actully getting a (useful!) answer, if supply some details. details of error messages you get for example.

Comment: @barryhunter the output which I am getting is nothing so there not showing any errors also .. so I have no idea why it is not converting .. when provide .wav file it is working ... but not working in .mp3

Comment: Did you reed https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/faq/#q-how-can-i-decode-audio-encoded-with-a-codec-mp3-mu-law-mp4-g729

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback.....

Comment: @barryhunter is there any other codes for decode mp3 files in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

As it is specified in the CMU Sphinx documents, only the linear PCM WAV audio format is accept by its speech recognizer. Therefore, any MP3 audio file will be decoded to obtain the linear PCM format, of 16khz sampling rate, 16bit/frame, little-endian and one channel (mono).
This decoding is achieved by the Tarsos Transcoder 1.2. This library uses many Apache utilities, therefore beside the TarsosTranscoder.jar, mp3plugin.jar also has to be included in the project building path.